# Missing ~/.subversion/servers file?

Tags: svn

I was looking for the ~/.subversion/servers file, but don't seem to have the ~/.subversion directory anywhere on my system.  I am running a Win 7x64 system, and have tried both a native Windows SVN build (from the command prompt) as well as a cygwin ported version.

I have checked in both c:\users\.subversion (doesn't exist) and as well in my cygwin home directory C:\cygwin\home\ (or ~/ in the cygwin shell).

I don't have a .subversion directory in either location, and have tried running basic svn commands.

Am using svn 1.7.5 in both cases.  Is the servers file no longer automatically generated if it is missing?  If I create it by hand, am I guaranteed that svn will read it?

Comment: Maybe Application Data\Subversion? Also, see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.confarea.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Cygwin-version was wrong choice
2. Global Subversion config-files are (in Windows) always in /%APPDATA%/Subversion